# Не могу правильно расположить текст

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Суть моей проблемы в следующем. Я не могу правильно настроить позицию текста в контейнере. Дал всему контейнеру позицию релатив, а нужный блок с текстом абсолютно, но что-то не выходит.
Что должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Html:

```
<div class="osnova">
    <p class="Title">Bring clarity to your team</p>
    <p class="Bottom">Slite is a modern knowledge base that drives action with structured docs, thoughtful collaboration and
        confident decision-making.</p>
</div>
```

Css:

```
 .osnova {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 900px;
   position: relative;
}   


.Title {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 500;
    
}

.Bottom {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    

}
```

Comment: Непонятно зачем такие сложности с позиционированием. Вроде на картинке обычный центрированный текст.

Comment: Не, это понятно и у меня получилось его сделать, текст вроде по центру, но мне нужно чтобы текст второго параграфа не выходил за границы первого, а я это не понимаю как сделать.

Comment: @Shelkovs имелось ввиду абсолютное позиционирование, оно ведь с шириной текста Вам никак не помогает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не профи в css и написал такой кастыль с уменьшением ширины текста:

```
css

.osnova {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 800px;
}   


.Title {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 500;
    
}

.Bottom {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 700px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Метод рабочий, но могут возникнуть проблемы при подстраивание под другие устройства. Ещё одним минусом является вечная тонкая настройка ширины текста вместо нормального метода.

Comment: А вот на столько легко эт решается. Пасиб большое, подгоню и пойдёт)